# How to replace exact string to other using replace() of Panda.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I'd like to replace all '0-4' to '00-04' in 'tumor-size' column in my DataFrame. What I have in the column is following.

```
print(df['tumor-size'].unique())
["'15-19'" "'35-39'" "'30-34'" "'25-29'" "'40-44'" "'10-14'" "'0-4'" "'20-24'" "'45-49'" "'50-54'" "'5-9'"]
```

What I tried at 1st place and nothing changed is following.

```
df['tumor-size'] = df['tumor-size'].replace('0-4', '00-04')
```

Next, I tried is following. In this case, all '0-4' were replaced w/ '00-40', however all '40-44' were  replaced w/ '400-044' since '40-44' contains '0-4'.

```
df['tumor-size'] = df['tumor-size'].str.replace('0-4', '00-04')
```

I read other QAs and noticed me that I need regex. Then I tried following since the elements always start with '0-4', but nothing changed again.

```
df['tumor-size'] = df['tumor-size'].str.replace(r'^0-4', '00-04', regex=True)
```

What I want to do is quite simple but I have no idea how to realize this.
Please someone help me.
Thank you,

Note: I reload all data to df from csv file at Every single try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df['tumor-size'] = df['tumor-size'].replace("^'0-4'$", "'00-04'")
```

Comment: It worked! All elements like '0-4' are warped with " ". That was the reason of failure. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'tumor-size': ['15-19', '35-39', '30-34', '25-29',
                                       '40-44', '10-14', '0-4', '20-24',
                                       '45-49', '50-54', '5-9']})
df['tumor-size'] = df['tumor-size'].str.replace(r'^0-4$', '00-04', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   tumor-size
0       15-19
1       35-39
2       30-34
3       25-29
4       40-44
5       10-14
6       00-04
7       20-24
8       45-49
9       50-54
10        5-9
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. @U13-Forward's answer didn't work for me in Colab.